# Changing the axis labeling in a Excel 2010 scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts, axis

I am trying to represent a list of data points in such a way that the graph starts at X coordinate '1' but that labeling starts at coordinate '100' and I have been unable to find out how to do it as all the obvious methods that I can find shift the start of the graph instead of just the labeling.!

The way I want it to look (these images are made with a different program)
[image: The way I want it to look (these images are made with a different program)]

The way my current excel 'best' attempt looks
[image: The way my current excel 'best' attempt looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel can do this pretty well, with the right data setup.  For your example, you can do it with five columns.

1. Set up your data

   - Column A numeric counter (1,2,3,4,5...n)
   - Column B Label (180, 181, 182...n+180)
   - Column C Chart Value (whatever your data is)
   - Column D either =NA() (for most rows) or equals your Column A value for rows you want labled.
   - Column E either =NA() (same as Column D) or equals your Column C value for rows you want labeled.
2. Insert a Column Chart using the following settings:

   - Series Values = Column C (this will create a standard column chart of your values)
   - Horizontal Axis Labels = Column B (this will use your defined labels for the axis)
3. Create your staggered labels:

   - Add another series using Column E values (this becomes the base info for your labels, with only the label points showing, the NA()'s show blank)
   - Select that second series and Change Chart Type to Scatter Chart.
   - Modify that second series' X Values = Column D, Y Values = Column E (this will create a data point wherever you want a label)
   - Select that second series and Add Data Labels
4. Format the whole chart to your taste

   - Remove grid lines
   - Format the second series to No Markers
   - Format the second series data labels to your preference (although horizontal is better than rotated vertical)
   - Format horizontal axis to Label Interval is 200
   - And whatever else you like

The final product should look something like this:

[image: Column with Staggered Labels]

Comment: There is nothing simple as axis offset?

Comment: I will accept your answer because of the effort you made in answering it. I didn't use it in the end (I just set the Y-axis start value at 180 and 'erased' the leading part in Gimp).

Answer (score 0):

I would make the chart as an XY chart, where I have data points (no lines or markers) at the tops of the "bars", and show the bars as vertical error bars, using the Minus option, with a percentage of 100.
For the labels, I'd hide the default labels, and add another XY series with X values where I want a label and Y values of zero. Again, these points would have no marker. I'd add data labels below the points using the "Categories" or "X-Values" option.